# Is there an end to Palpatine's missions?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have 50 floors so far, and I have noticed that the green death star hologram behind palpatine keeps growing in size as I build up my death star. Does this happen because I do palpatine's missions or because I build up more levels? And is there an end to palpatine's missions? Will it end when the death star hologram behind him grows full?

Comment: Interesting observation about the hologram...I'm at 61 levels and it looks to be about 80% full.  The problem with his missions are that they are worth absolutely nothing...I haven't seen one more than 800 coins.  It's kind of annoying: vader's missions actually become fun and are rewarding, then abruptly end early on, while palpatine's missions are kind of just play the game and not rewarding at all.

Comment: If you look below, I've added a pic of the completed Death Star.  So, at 81 levels it fills in completely, even though there is no end.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I built all the Service floors, and now Palpatine wants me, according to his genius "plans", to build one more, which is kinda impossible for now... Palpatine's always full of surprises. ;)

So this let me believe he will always summon up new missions randomly. Until you ran out of bux trying to skip the impossible ones.

Comment: dbernard - Interesting!  Did you skip any missions early on, and they've come back to haunt you now?  Or is this just a completely random mission?

Comment: Nah I did not skipped any missions, but I did not always followed his plan either.

Comment: I've built all the levels, and "add another level" still,appears at the top. Palpatine's current mission is "add another level"! Is there any interesting end to this game?

Answer (score 2):

I have built every floor (including Panna City Medicines twice!).  The Emperor is requesting that I build 2 more of any floor.

I think he's taunting me.

[image: Stupid Mission]

Also, in case anyone is interested, I caught a screenshot of the "completed" death star . . .

[image: Completed]

Answer (score 1):

There is an end to the imperial quests but haven't seen any for the emperor